# Get all column names from sharepoint list java

Tags: java, sharepoint

I'm reading a SharePoint list with java via a web service.

I've seen a number of examples that will read the list based on column titles you provide as an input.

Id like to know how to read all the items in a SharePoint list and get a list of all the column names (internal preferably).

Thanks for your thoughts guys

Comment: Can you show the actual code, rather than an explanation of what it should be doing?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link will help you:

http://blog.ashwani.co.in/blog/2013-07-28/connect-and-access-sharepoint-webservice-from-java/

see the `displaySharePointList()` method he applies no query or queryOption and I think this will display all list items.

But if you want to get a list of the column names you have to create a CAML query (this is very vague answer but I don't know the perfect answer yet as I am looking into this by myself atm).

Edit: I found this great program helps you to create CAMLQueries:

https://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/

cheers

Answer (score 1):

This will get the column internal names without decoding.

```
NamedNodeMap attributes = listResult.getElementsByTagName("z:row").item(0).getAttributes();

for (int i=0; i<attributa.getLength(); i++){

   System.out.println("name: "+attributa.item(i).getNodeName());

   }
```

However, it does not show the hidden columns. Any idea how?

Answer (score 0):

```
GetListItemsResponse.GetListItemsResult result = listsoap.getListItems(listName, "", msQuery, viewFields, null, queryOptions, webID);
    Object listResult = result.getContent().get(0);
    if(listResult != null){
        Element element = (Element)result.getContent().get(0);
        NodeList nl = element.getElementsByTagName("z:row");
        System.out.println("\n=> " + nl.getLength() + " results from SharePoint Online\n");
        for(Integer i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++){
             NamedNodeMap attributes = nl.item(i).getAttributes();
             System.out.println(attributes.getNamedItem("ows_Title").getNodeValue());
        }
```

This is the code currently being used. However I am having to specify the internal name explicitly in order to retrieve its data. Isn't there a way to retrieve all the internal names of the SharePointList via Java?